# How do I add a Bookmarklet to the Navigation Bar in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarklet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add firefox bookmark as toolbar button](https://superuser.com/questions/65564/how-to-add-firefox-bookmark-as-toolbar-button)

I'm trying to find a way to add a single bookmarklet to the navigation bar in Firefox 7 - any method (add-on, hack, Greasemonkey script) is fine by me, but haven't been able to find anything that works so far.

Because I only have one bookmarklet that I need, I really don't want to have the bookmark toolbar enabled and take up all that screen real estate - hence, I'm wondering if there's a way to create an extra icon on the navigation bar (alongside the Search Bar and Home, Bookmarks, New Tab, etc buttons) that contains the bookmarklet.

Answer (score 2):

You can perhaps use [Custom Buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/custom-buttons/).

I don't know how it handles complicated scripts, but I'm using it successfully to do some trivial tasks, e.g.

- a button which opens Google in new tab (instead of current):

  `gBrowser.selectedTab = gBrowser.addTab("http://www.google.com/");`
- a button which performs `site:` Google search over current URL:

  `content.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:' + content.location.hostname;`
- Same button, but with prompt:

  ```
  var q=prompt("Search terms:").replace(/\s\+/g,"%252B");
  var loc="http://www.google.com/search?q="+q
  loc += "+site:"+content.location.hostname;
  content.location = loc;
  ```

To create nice image buttons, you can use Notepad++ to base64-encode the icon or PNG image:

```
data:image/x-icon;base64,[data here]
data:image/png;base64,[data here]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button that opens your bookmarks in a sidebar. Thats the only solution I can come up with.

```
View -> Toolbars -> Customize... -> Display your bookmarks
```

There's also a keyboard shortcut for it (`Command+B` on Mac || `CTRL + B` on Windows)

That's all I can come up with, maybe it's already what you need.

Comment: You didn't read his question - QO doesn't want the bookmarks toolbar

Comment: @Shedokan The QO didn't want the Bookmark TOOLBAR, I offered him to open a sidebar, which - in contrast to the toolbar - you can toggle easily. Just one click/toggle more than with a drop-down menu (what he propably wants)

Comment: @DanSurfrider unfortunately that still creates an extra set of clicking, when what I'd really like to be able to do is utilize the bookmarklet with a single click (and not lose all the screen space from the toolbar or sidebar)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I misread your answer.